# TF not moving in navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm following the wiki tutorial for the navigation stack, however, when I launch it,

- the tf in the map seems not moving when I physically move it and
- it doesn't move as well when I tried to use 2D pose estimate as well. But the local footprint polygon and laser scanning data flashes continuously between the tf and the selected location.

Anyone knows what the problem is? (will that be because of the static tf publisher of odom to footprint?)

Here's the robot_configuration.launch

```
<launch>
  <node name="ydlidar_node"  pkg="ydlidar"  type="ydlidar_node" output="screen"/>    

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /map /odom 40" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_basefootprint" 
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /odom /base_footprint 40" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_to_base_link"
    args="0 0.0 0 0.0 0.0  0.0 /base_footprint /base_link 40" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser_frame"
    args="0.2245 0.0 0 1.57 3.14  0.0 /base_link /laser_frame 40" />

  <node pkg="rf2o_laser_odometry" type="rf2o_laser_odometry_node" name="rf2o_laser_odometry">
    <param name="laser_scan_topic" value="/scan"/>        
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_link"/>            
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom" />               
    <param name="freq" value="6.0"/>                        
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find mobilet_2dnav)/rviz_cfg/configuration.rviz"/>
    
</launch>
```

and the move_base.launch

```
<launch>

   <master auto="start"/>
 <!-- Run the map server --> 
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/maps/office_4.yaml"/>

 <!--- Run AMCL --> 
    <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" />

   <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" /> 
    <rosparam file="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" /> 
    <rosparam file="$(find mobilet_2dnav)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
 </node>

</launch>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

**Edit:**
followed Delb's suggestions, I changed parameter of the rf2o_laser_odometry node:

```
 <node pkg="rf2o_laser_odometry" type="rf2o_laser_odometry_node" name="rf2o_laser_odometry" output="screen">
    <param name="laser_scan_topic" value="/scan"/>        # topic where the lidar scans are being published
    <param name="odom_topic" value="/odom_rf2o" />      # topic where tu publish the odometry estimations
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true" />                     # wheter or not to publish the tf::transform (base->odom)
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_footprint"/>      # frame_id (tf) of the mobile robot base. A tf transform from the laser_frame to the base_frame is mandatory
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom" />                 # frame_id (tf) to publish the odometry estimations    
    <param name="init_pose_from_topic" value="" />        # (Odom topic) Leave empty to start at point (0,0)
    <param name="freq" value="6.0"/>                               # Execution frequency.
    <param name="verbose" value="true" />  
  </node>
```

and my tf_tree:[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316037/tf-not-moving-in-navigation-stack/) by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are defining to much static transforms. The static transform won't move since they are static so your robot won't move at all.

The `AMCL` is responsible to publish the `tf` between `map` and `odom` so you have a conflict between `AMCL` and your static transform. Moreover it's your node `rf2_laser_odometry` that will deal with the tf between `base_link` and `odom` so all you have to do is get rid of these nodes :

```
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /map /odom 40" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_basefootprint" 
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /odom /base_footprint 40" />
```

You probably need to change the parameter `base_frame_id` to :

```
<param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_footprint"/>
```

---

**Edit :** There are too much parameters for your node `rf2o_laser_odometry`, it should be like that :

```
 <node pkg="rf2o_laser_odometry" type="rf2o_laser_odometry_node" name="rf2o_laser_odometry" output="screen">
    <param name="laser_scan_topic" value="/scan"/>               
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_footprint"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom" /> 
    <param name="freq" value="6.0"/> 
  </node>
```

I've deleted the other params because they don't exist for this node. For the frequence I would set a higher rate, at least the same as for the static transforms (40).

For odom you can choose whatever you want as long as the other nodes needing odom (the topic not the frame) are correctly remapped (that's why I would keep it as `odom`).

For `roswtf` I don't know why you have those warnings the tf tree looks right (even more if you say that the frame moves correctly), maybe it's due to the frequence or simply because of your rviz configuration which was using the old static transforms that you have now removed. Maybe if you try launching `rviz` with the default configuration and then running `roswtf` the warning might disappear.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-20**:
Million Thanks Delb!  tf moves correspondingly now! just when i run `roswtf`, it shows:

```
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rf2o_laser_odometry:
   * /tf_static
 * /amcl:
   * /tf_static
```

am I missing anything? or should they be connected in other way?

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-20**:
Also, I noticed that /odom seems publishing nothing while /odom_rf2o does, do I need to change it to /odom? Hope you can answer! Thanks!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-20**:
Have you modified the node `rf2o_laser_odometry` ? It should publish `odom` not `odom_rf2o`.
About roswtf, can you edit your question to add a picture of the `tf_tree` ? Also if you could detail what you've changed exactly that would be clearer.

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-20**:
just edited the question for more info. Should I actually change the "odom_topic" to /odom too?

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-21**:
I have tried a while, but not sure why when I delete the line for "publish_tf" and "init_pose_from_topic", the lidar doesn't publish data (while it is still spinning), so I keep both lines.

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-21**:
Also found that rf2o node seems just take data from /scan (while lidar is installed upside down as indicated in static tf.), so robot moves to right in reality but moving to left in the map.But from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rf2o_laser_odometry),the node does subcribe tf..do you have idea of this?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-21**:
That might be due to how you define the static frame here :

```
args="0.2245 0.0 0 1.57 3.14  0.0 /base_link /laser_frame 40"
```

That indicates that you rotate the frame around `x by pi/2` but also around `y by pi`. You should only rotate around `x by pi`.

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-22**:
My bad description.. I actually flipped the lidar upside down and turned it around z for pi/2.. and tf displayed is correct..
I used the above static transform for hector slam for creating map, and the tf moves correspondingly when I move the robot..just not so sure why it doesn't right here...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-22**:
So is it corrected now or still wrong ? If you have flipped the lidar upside down and then rotated around z your static frame is still wrong and should be :

```
args="0.2245 0.0 0 3.14 0 1.57  /base_link /laser_frame 40"
```

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-22**:
Just a little tip : It's a little bit hard to read your args because sometimes you have `0` and other times you have `0.0` that makes things a little bit unclear. You should choose to set always `0.0` or just `0` but not both.

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-22**:
Thank you so much, Delb for the advice. I have put the rviz display of tf in the question, it shows the right tf I have set up. allow me to explain a little more. The map is created with hector slam, while I'm running hector slam with the same tf (0.2245 0 0 1.57 3.14 0). Map is the same as the room

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-02-22**:
(not flipped around any axis). Also, robot moves to right, so do the tf. From these, I think the tf defined is right.. But I dont get it why while I run navigation stack with the same tf, it just doesnt do the same, i.e. robot moves to right and displayed as moving to left..yet the scan fits the map